# repr and super in Python 2.7. `super().__repr__` vs `repr(super())`

Tags: python, python-2.7, super, internals, repr

### Question: Why is `repr(super(class, thing))` different from `super(class, thing).__repr__()`?

I've come across something that I think is odd, would be great if someone has an explanation for why this works the way it does.

My question is about how `repr` works

```
class MyInt(int):
    pass

one = MyInt(1)
sup = super(MyInt, one)
```

`>>> repr(sup)`

`"<super: <class 'MyInt'>, <MyInt object>>"`

while

`>>> sup.__repr__()`

`'1'`

The second is what I expected to come from the first (yes, the quotes are different in each case). **Why are these cases of `repr` different?** I thought `repr(x)` just called `x.__repr__`.

---

As far as I know, `super` provides an API to the methods of the super class, rather than the super class itself. So it seems to me that my `sup` has two `__repr__` methods, one which is called by the `repr` and one which is under the name `__repr__`. Would really appreciate some insight into what's going on here.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking why `super(MyInt, one).__repr__()` and `repr(super(MyInt, one))` are different?

Comment: exactly, I thought the second was just calling the first